# Powerline tmux default configuration

Tags: tmux, powerline

I have installed powerline in tmux via

```
powerline-config tmux setup
```

It looks great, but I've looked through the docs and I don't see defined what means what. Most of it is obvious, but there are three numbers here that I don't understand.

[image]

Can anybody clarify? Also, how might I customise it? (I tried to read the friendly manual but...here I am)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [default `tmux` theme](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/blob/develop/powerline/config_files/themes/tmux/default.json) in `powerline`. The first represents the system uptime and the second represents the system load.

You can customize themes by copying the config files to `$HOME/.config/powerline` and then editing the entries. You can [read more here](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).